# Bash - how to escape underscore in URL

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, wget

I have a little script in `bash` on `macOS`, where I use an array with dates like `19000105` in the format `yyyymmdd`.

In that script I parse the dates of that array to a loop like:

```
for i in "${list[@]}"; do
    wget -A pdf -nc -E -nd --no-check-certificate URL$iURL$i_tif.pdf
done
```

where `wget` opens an URL to download pdf. In order to make it work I need to add the date twice to the URL at different parts.

The URL, however, contains at one point an underscore right after I insert the date, which needs to look like this: `19000105_tif/jpegs/`.

I thought I need to add curled brackets like `{$i}_tif/` to escape, however, the URL is parsed like `%7B18500105%7D_tif/`, which is wrong.

If I leave the curled brackets like `$i_tif/`, the URL is parsed like `/jpegs/`, where the date and `tif`-part before is not parsed at all and completely gone.

How can I add the dates correctly with an underscore in the URL right after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `${i}` instead of `$i` should solve this